# Delete record from two tables having same id

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is the records are not deleting at a same time in two tables.i Got the success message when select the link of delete.However deleted from stock table but not in the category table.
After deleted from stock,again delete the record
then record delete from category table

1)deletecategoryselect.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    //check if user is logged in,
    if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']))
    {
        header("Location:index.php?page=admin");
    }


?>

<h1>Delete Category</h1>
<?php $delcat_sql="SELECT * FROM category";         // get data
$delcat_query=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $delcat_sql); 
$delcat_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($delcat_query);
do 
{ ?>
<p><a href="index.php?page=deletecategoryconfirm&categoryID=<?php echo 
$delcat_rs['categoryID']; ?>"><?php echo $delcat_rs['name']; ?></a></p>

<?php
} while ($delcat_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($delcat_query));

?>
```

2)deletecategoryconfirm.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    //check if user is logged in,
    if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']))
    {
        header("Location:index.php?page=admin");
    }


?>

<h1>Confirm Category to Delete</h1>

<?php 
$delcat_sql="SELECT * FROM category WHERE categoryID=".$_GET['categoryID'];
$delcat_query=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $delcat_sql);
$delcat_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($delcat_query); 

// check if there are any stock items in this category
$check_sql="SELECT * FROM stock WHERE categoryID=".$_GET['categoryID'];
$check_query=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $check_sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($check_query);

?>
<p>
<?php 
    if($count>0)
        {
            echo "Warning!!! <br> There are ".$count." stock item(s) in this 
category. If you delete the category they will also be delete from 
database";
        } 
?>
</p>

<p><?php echo "Do you really wish to delete : ".$delcat_rs['name']."?"; ?>
</p>
<p><a href="index.php?page=deletecategory&categoryID=<?php echo 
$_GET['categoryID']; ?>"> Yes, delete it!</a> | 
<a href="index.php?page=deletecategoryselect"> No, go back</a> | 
<a href="index.php?page=admin"> Back to admin panel</a>
</p>
```

3)deletecategory.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //check if user is logged in,
    if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']))
    {
        header("Location:index.php?page=admin");
    }

    $delcat_sql="DELETE FROM category WHERE 
    categoryID=".$_GET['categoryID'];
    $delcat_query=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $delcat_sql);

    $delstock_sql="DELETE FROM stock WHERE categoryID=".$_GET['categoryID'];
    $delstock_query=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $delstock_sql);


?>

<h1>Category Deleted</h1>
<p>Category has successfully been deleted</p>

<p><a href="index.php?page=admin">Return to admin panel</a> | <a 
href="index.php?page=deletecategoryselect" >Return to Delete category 
select</a></p>
```

Comment: I don't get it. If you just want to DELETE, why bother with all the SELECTs? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query